# I want to create a new local variable from the sum of two others in Ruby but I'm stuck

Tags: ruby

I am trying to change one example to take a user input rather than using hard coded values then use those local variables to work out items needed.

So far my code looks like this:

```
print "Number of cars available today." 
cars = gets.chomp()
print "Number of available seats in the car."
space_in_a_car = gets.chomp()
print "Number of drivers available."
drivers = gets.chomp()
print "Number of passagers that need transport."
passangers = gets.chomp

cars_not_driven = #{cars} - #{drivers}
cars_driven = drivers
carpool_capacity = #{cars_driven} * #{space_in_a_car}
average_passanger_per_car = #{passangers} / #{drivers}

print "The number of cars being driven today is #{cars_driven}.\n"
print "The number of cars not being driven today is #{cars_not_driven}.\n"
print "We have #{carpool_capacity} cars available.\n"
print "So we need to carry #{average_passanger_per_car} passangers per car to make sure we can transport everyone.\n"
```

The code will run without throwing any errors but of course because I am not getting the correct commands in:

```
cars_not_driven = #{cars} - #{drivers}
cars_driven = drivers
carpool_capacity = #{cars_driven} * #{space_in_a_car}
average_passanger_per_car = #{passangers} / #{drivers}
```

the only value I am getting in the return is:

```
print "The number of cars being driven today is #{cars_driven}.\n"
```

How should I be writing:

```
cars_not_driven = #{cars} - #{drivers} etc
```

to get the number of `cars_not_driven`?

Comment: Note that outside of string literals, `#` starts a comment.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `gets` Ruby is expecting and returning a String. So variables `car`, `drivers` etc are all String.

In order to do integer operation over them, you need to convert them to integers. In Ruby you can do this using `.to_i`.

Now with that information, try:

```
cars_not_driven = cars.to_i - drivers.to_i
cars_driven = drivers.to_i
carpool_capacity = cars_driven * space_in_a_car.to_i
average_passanger_per_car = passangers.to_i / drivers.to_i
```

You can check the class of a variable using `.class`. Here:

```
cars = gets.chomp()
10
# => "10"
cars.class
# => String

drivers = gets.chomp()
20
# => "20"
drivers.class
# => String
```

Now lets add them:

```
cars + drivers
# => "1020"
```

Since they are string, `+` operator is adding two strings to one. Not something you intended. Now try this:

```
cars.to_i + drivers.to_i
# => 30
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well why you use this `#{var}` and `<br>`. If I am right that you want to use plain ruby, this should be the solution:

```
print "Number of cars available today." 
cars = gets.chomp().to_i
print "Number of available seats in the car."
space_in_a_car = gets.chomp().to_i
print "Number of drivers available."
drivers = gets.chomp().to_i
print "Number of passagers that need transport."
passangers = gets.chomp.to_i

cars_not_driven = cars - drivers
cars_driven = drivers
carpool_capacity = cars_driven * space_in_a_car
average_passanger_per_car = passangers / drivers

print "The number of cars being driven today is #{cars_driven}.\n"
print "The number of cars not being driven today is #{cars_not_driven}.\n"
print "We have #{carpool_capacity} cars available.\n"
print "So we need to carry #{average_passanger_per_car} passangers per car to make sure we can transport everyone.\n"
```

Comment: The `<br>`s were introduced by another user's edit, I've already removed them.